# How to accept the google permission prompt by default while using appium

Tags: appium, python-appium

I'm trying to automate the app , but suddenly in middle the google permissions window for permission like phone , location etc pops up , is there any way that I can make sure always permission pop ups are allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set desired capabilities:

```
autoAcceptAlerts = true
```

Comment: if autoAcceptAlerts is set to true in iOS all alerts shown in the application will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said google permissions, I am assuming you are dealing in `Android`. Also since there is no language tag, I am sticking to `Java`, you can frame the logic in any language you are using.

Well, its sad to inform you that currently there seems to be no such capability added for android. Though `iOS` has few similar [capabilities](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#ios-only).
So, for android what you can do is logically -

1. If these pop-ups are device dependent, change the device settings that these pop-ups are not allowed.
2. If these pop-ups are relevant to application permissions, then you must know when they would occur. Just keep a check -

   ```
   List<WebElement> popUp = driver.findElement(<find the pop up using your locator strategy>);
   if(popUp.size()!=0) {
     WebElement accept/dismiss = driver.findElement(<find the button accordingly>);
     accept/dismiss.click();
   }
   ```